# How to use NLog in multiple classes

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, nlog

I am learning to use NLog. My situation is I want to use it inside DLL probably wrap it inside a log class. Basically my goals are:

1) I want this configuration to occur only **ONCE**:

```
    var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

    var fileTarget = new FileTarget();     
    config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);

     // Step 3. Set target properties 
     fileTarget.Layout = @"${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss} - ${message}";
     fileTarget.FileName = "c:/myFolder/" + "${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log";

     var rule2 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, fileTarget);
     config.LoggingRules.Add(rule2);

     // Step 5. Activate the configuration
     LogManager.Configuration = config;

     // Example usage
     _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Example");
```

If it will be relevant I also want to be able to specify say as the parameter the log file path to the initialization routine.

2) Any other class should be able to call a method like LogWrapper.Log("message"), which should log messages using my configured NLog object - I know which method of NLog writes the entry to log file, that is not a problem, say it is called `_logger.write`.

How can I achieve this in a **(thread)** safe way?
I have been struggling with this for a while already and would appreciate much help! This should not be that hard right, basically I am asking how to use NLog.

Answer (score 0):

you deleted your previous question which answer this one so let me go at it again,

for #1, you need to put this code in a static constructor

ex;

```
  static class test
  {
       static test() 
       { /* ... code */}
  }
```

for #2 to be safe you need a locker ex;

```
  static class test
  {
       private static object _locker = new object();

       static test() 
       { /* ... code */}

        public static void log(string msg)
        {
           lock(_locker )
           { /* ... code */}
        }
  }
```

Comment: If I put init code in static constructor, why do I need lock inside log method? isn't NLog already thread safe?

Comment: Also I might need to pass a parameter such as log file path to initialization routine, please address that too - since static constructor doesn't support that

Comment: @Quser, for that one, go back to your initial question that you delete, you have your answer right there, a static method with parameter that will check if it was initialized or not

Comment: and I pass parameter to that init method? Please check I asked some question, there too